# GBenchmark and CMake

Tags: cmake, google-benchmark

From relevant search on the web, I got an impression that
`google-benchmark` is not easily incorporated into a CMake-project.
One way I could do that is adding as external project,
replicating verbatim the corresponding text for `GTest` in google-test's readme:

```
# adding google-benchmark as external git project
#=======================================================
configure_file(extern/googlebenchmark/CMakeLists.txt.in googlebenchmark-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googlebenchmark-download)
if(result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googlebenchmark failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googlebenchmark-download )
if(result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googlebenchmark failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gbenchmark_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googlebenchmark-src
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googlebenchmark-build
        EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
    include_directories("${gbenchmark_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()
```

and having `CMakeLists.txt.in` with the contents as in
[How to build and link google benchmark using cmake in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376111/how-to-build-and-link-google-benchmark-using-cmake-in-windows)

This however has a huge downside: every time we change something in the `CMakeLists.txt` -- the topmost one -- that hosts all this, it starts building google-benchmark from scratch,
and running all the "tests", whatever they are. Thus compilation times become longer.

Without a root access to a Linux server, is there any more-less portable way
of having the benchmark code installed in one's home directory, while being
able to link towards it in a CMake-project?

EDIT: I must say I've been able to `git clone` the benchmark code and successfully built it in my home directory.

EDIT: Answering my own question. I am not sure if this warrants a close, and leave it to the patrons to decide, but I've solved the problem as follows. In the `CMakeLists.txt` one can have the following contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(sample_bench sample_bench.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sample_bench PUBLIC benchmark benchmark_main pthread)
target_link_directories(sample_bench PUBLIC ~/local/benchmark/build/src)
target_include_directories(sample_bench PUBLIC
        ~/local/benchmark/include)
```

The key here is `target_link_directories`, which is specified with `-L` in the example in https://github.com/google/benchmark

Comment: If you have found an answer to your issue, please post an [answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. I've solved the problem as follows. In the CMakeLists.txt one can have the following contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(sample_bench sample_bench.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sample_bench PUBLIC benchmark benchmark_main pthread)
target_link_directories(sample_bench PUBLIC ~/local/benchmark/build/src)
target_include_directories(sample_bench PUBLIC
        ~/local/benchmark/include)
```

The key here is target_link_directories, which is specified with `-L` in the example in https://github.com/google/benchmark
This is enough to run the sample benchmark, at least -- haven't tried others.
That is, once you have built benchmark somewhere -- even in your home directory, as in the example -- you can point `CMake` to the designated locations,
in order for your code to compile.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

I've also tried to "Add the installation prefix of "benchmark" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "benchmark_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files [benchmarkConfig.cmake, that is benchmark/build/src/generated/]." but none of the two ways worked. I mean `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} ~/benchmark/build/")` or 
`set(benchmark_DIR "~/benchmark/build/src/generated/")` in conjunction with
`find_package(benchmark REQUIRED)`. I found the directions to do so after including `find_package(benchmark REQUIRED)`.